# Reemplazar valores de string en Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

tengo una columna (Fecha) que está en formato character y necesito transformarla a numeric, pero antes necesito estandarizar los valores de las observaciones.

Tengo estos datos:

```
|Fecha
--------
"Miércoles 02/11/2022 08:54:56" 
"Jueves 03/11/2022 08:54:57" 
"Viernes 04/11/2022 08:54:57"
"Sábado 05/11/2022 08:54:59" 
"Miércoles 02/11/2022 08:54:59" 
"Viernes 04/11/2022 08:55:00"
"Domingo 06/11/2022 08:55:01"
```

Y necesito reemplazar todos los días de semana por números (lunes = 1, martes= 2, miércoles= 3, etc.), eliminar los caracteres "/" y ":" de modo que quede de esta forma:

```
Fecha
------
"0302112022085456" 
"0403112022085457" 
"0504112022085457"
"0605112022085459" 
"0302112022085459" 
"0504112022085500"
"0706112022085501"
```

**Use el siguiente código y me funcionó, pero es muy largo. Habrá alguna manera de acortarlo?**

*disciplinar es la base y Fecha la variable

```
disciplinar$Fecha <- str_replace(disciplinar$Fecha, "Lunes ","01")
disciplinar$Fecha <- str_replace(disciplinar$Fecha, "Martes ","02")
disciplinar$Fecha <- str_replace(disciplinar$Fecha, "Miércoles ","03")
disciplinar$Fecha <- str_replace(disciplinar$Fecha, "Jueves ","04")
disciplinar$Fecha <- str_replace(disciplinar$Fecha, "Viernes ","05")
disciplinar$Fecha <- str_replace(disciplinar$Fecha, "Sábado ","06")
disciplinar$Fecha <- str_replace(disciplinar$Fecha, "Doming ","07")

#Eliminar caracteres especiales
disciplinar$Fecha <- str_replace(disciplinar$Fecha, " ","") #eliminar espacios
disciplinar$Fecha <- str_replace(disciplinar$Fecha, "/","") #eliminar /
disciplinar$Fecha <- str_replace(disciplinar$Fecha, ":","") #eliminar :
```

De antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre algo así:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(solo_fecha = gsub("[^0-9]", "", Fecha),
         dia = factor(gsub("[^[:alpha:]]", "", Fecha), 
                      levels =  c("Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", 
                                  "Viernes", "Sábado", "Domingo")),
         new_fecha = paste0("0", as.numeric(dia), solo_fecha)
  ) %>% 
  select(Fecha, new_fecha)

                           Fecha        new_fecha
1  Miércoles 02/11/2022 08:54:56 0302112022085456
2     Jueves 03/11/2022 08:54:57 0403112022085457
3    Viernes 04/11/2022 08:54:57 0504112022085457
4     Sábado 05/11/2022 08:54:59 0605112022085459
5 Miércoles 02/11/2022 08:54:59  0302112022085459
6    Viernes 04/11/2022 08:55:00 0504112022085500
7    Domingo 06/11/2022 08:55:01 0706112022085501
```

Comentarios:

- Con `gsub("[^0-9]", "", Fecha)` nos quedamos solo con lo números
- Con `gsub("[^[:alpha:]]", "", Fecha)`  solo con las palabras (nombre del día)
- Generamos un `factor` especificando las etiquetas con los nombres de semana
- Por último convertimos este `factor` en un número, lo que nos dá el código numérico.
- Se asume que el formato es siempre el mismo y no tenemos valores `NA` ni nombres de día mas allá de los indicados.